# gulp build output not in Heroku slug

Tags: node.js, heroku, gulp

I have a super-simple gulpfile which works locally:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('build:css', function() {
  return gulp.src('./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/*')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'));
});

gulp.task('build:js', function() {
  return gulp.src('./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/*')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'));
});

gulp.task('build', [ 'build:css', 'build:js' ]);
gulp.task('default', [ 'build' ]);
```

It runs fine and copies files to a 'build' subfolder.  In fact, it runs on `git push heroku master` too (it's a `postinstall` script in `package.json`):

```
remote:        > gulp build
remote:
remote:        [06:57:45] Using gulpfile /tmp/build_212ea9c2c3fab185469156431b6c1509/coming-soon/gulpfile.js
remote:        [06:57:45] Starting 'build:css'...
remote:        [06:57:45] Starting 'build:js'...
remote:        [06:57:45] Finished 'build:css' after 17 ms
remote:        [06:57:45] Finished 'build:js' after 8.18 ms
remote:        [06:57:45] Starting 'build'...
remote:        [06:57:45] Finished 'build' after 46 μs
```

However, when the app runs, the `build` folder does not exist:

```
$ heroku run ls
Running ls on something... up, run.7113
gulpfile.js  index.pug  node_modules  package.json  server.js
```

There's no `.slugignore`.  I've tried using `./`, `__dirname` and nothing at all as a path prefix in the gulpfile, but nothing gets the build folder into the output.

What else can I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had `gulp` as a `dependencies` entry, but not `bootstrap`.  If only I was outputting a file count, I'd see that `./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/*` and the JS counterpart matched 0 files, since `boostrap` wasn't `npm installed`-ed.

The fix: any build dependencies need to be in `dependencies` and not `devDependencies` in `package.json`.  I just missed this one.